# How to restrict PHP file access to execution directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, filesystems

I have a bunch of PHP scripts inside of, say, `/public_html/mydir/`, and these scripts may possibly try to delete files / do other stuff to the filesystem.

I want to allow all filesystem modifications within the `/public_html/mydir/` directory, but any access (or deletion) outside of the `mydir` directory shouild not be allowed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php and `open_basedir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either make a user that only has permission to access these directories, or you have to somehow run PHP in a sandbox like [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)